# Error when clicking on textview

Tags: android

What's the reason for this error? I only get the error at certain times when I press the textview.

```
12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at gps.app.tkartor.Tkartor.onClick(Tkartor.java:195)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-12 12:30:24.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(380):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> ```
>   <TextView android:id="@+id/tvReload" style="@style/ButtonText"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:text="PRESS TO RELOAD"
>         android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:textSize="12sp" android:clickable="true" />
> ```

Comment: post the xml layout code for button that you have declared.

Comment: paste code of TKartor.onClick() here and write the comment on 195 line at the end of line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Occurs when your object is null or not initiallized & you are trying to access it.

Crosscheck whether all your objects are properly initialized.

Specially in your code Check line number 195 of Tkartor.java file, there you have atleast one object null.

Comment: on Line 195 of your Tkartor class (in the onClick-method).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to dismiss a dialog that was null at some occasions, but not null at some which is why it worked to press the textview from time to time.